sf package install failing with MODULE_NOT_FOUND: Cannot find module 'glob'
I'm working on setting up a script to prepare a scratch org. In that script, I need to install a package, specifically Unofficial SF's Detect and Launch package. I'm doing that by running the command sf package install --package 04t5G000004C6tfQAC with the default org set to my current scratch org. I get the following error:
›   ModuleLoadError: [MODULE_NOT_FOUND] require failed to load /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-packaging/lib/commands/package/install.js: Cannot find module 'glob'
›   Require stack:
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/package/packageProfileApi.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/package/packageVersionCreate.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/package/packageConvert.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/package/package.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/package/index.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/packaging/lib/exported.js
›   - /Users/dylanbowman/.local/share/sf/node_modules/@salesforce/plugin-packaging/lib/commands/package/install.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/module-loader.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/help/index.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/handle.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/errors/index.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/cli-ux/index.js
›   - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli/node_modules/@oclif/core/lib/index.js
›   Code: MODULE_NOT_FOUND

When I run sf version, I get @salesforce/cli/2.39.6 darwin-arm64 node-v20.12.2. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the SF cli and removed any other version (including sfdx-cli). I've even tried npm install glob --global just to see if it does anything, and nothing. Same error.
Is anyone else experiencing this error trying to install packages? I can install through the web interface, but that will slow down development drastically.

I've just had the same issue, although when trying to create a new package version.
Uninstalling the SF CLI, and re-installing it using NPM (instead of using the instructions native to your OS) solved the issue:

npm install @salesforce/cli --global

EDIT: After then uninstalling via NPM, and re-installing via the native OS installer, the error message remained disappeared. Very strange.

This worked! Though I went the other way, installed and uninstalled from native installer, then NPM, and it worked. Really odd.

Same problem, same solution! Thanks, glad that worked.
Quick Link to Uninstall for Future Folk. This link tells you how to uninstall the cli and it is OS dependent. Please refer to it for specific guidance.

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Fair point. In this case, there are commands that need to be run and they are OS dependent. I'll add a little more context though.

I likewise had the issue when trying to create a package version, but I didn't have success installing/uninstalling npm. What finally worked for me was uninstalling SF using these commands (Mac & Linux):
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sfdx ~/.config/sfdx ~/.cache/sfdx
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sfdx
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/sf
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/sf
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/sf ~/.config/sf ~/.cache/sf
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/sf

These are the commands for Windows:
Select Start > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features.
Select @salesforce/cli, and click Uninstall.
Inside your home directory, delete these two directories:
.config\sfdx
.config\sf

If Salesforce CLI is still installed, delete these directories:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\sfdx
%LOCALAPPDATA%\sf

other install methods are covered here.
And then I reinstalled. Here are the links to the installers for each OS.

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

You're right. Thank you both for the suggestions. I've updated the answer.
